# Write registers for KSZ9031

Tags: kernel, embedded, ethernet

It's the first time I'm facing such a scenario and I don't know if it's ever possible.
My searches were unsuccessful perhaps because I didn't use the right keywords.

On an embedded Linux board the ethernet controller is a [KSZ9031RNX](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/268/00002117E-1112791.pdf). 
**Is it possible, from user-space, to write to the internal registers?**

> 3.8 10/100 Mbps Speeds Only
>
> Some applications require link-up to be limited to 10/100 Mbps speeds only.
>   After power-up/reset, the KSZ9031RNX can be restricted to auto-negotiate and link-up to 10/100 Mbps speeds only by programming the following register settings:
>
> 1. Set Register 0h, Bit [6] = ‘0’ to remove 1000 Mbps speed.
> 2. Set Register 9h, Bits [9:8] = ‘00’ to remove Auto-Negotiation advertisements for 1000 Mbps full-/half-duplex.
> 3. Write a ‘1’ to Register 0h, Bit [9], a self-clearing bit, to force a restart of Auto-Negotiation.

Is it possible to write these registers from command-line?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not possible, and it shouldn't be. Manipulating the hardware is the driver's job.

Linux has a command `ethtool` which allows all kinds of operations on the ethernet interface's parameters, including speed and auto-negotiation. If the device driver is reasonably well written it should support these operations.

However, I have no direct experience with a similar situation as yours, so can't give detailed instructions. You will have to experiment a bit until it does what you need.